# Do Magneto's powers work at faster than light speed?

Tags: marvel, x-men, magneto

According to the X-Men wikia, Magneto has a variety of powers including:

> the superhuman power to channel, manipulate, and generate magnetic fields that exist naturally or artificially

Is there a range on this power?  If the range is large or unlimited, is he able to manipulate magnetic fields across large distances at a speed faster than light?  For instance, if his target is one light year away, can he affect that target instantaneously or will it take a minimum of a year to affect it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Excalibur v.3, #8 (February 2005) it shows that Magneto can create a wormhole to travel through with others, which suggests that his powers over electromagnetic and gravitational fields is enough to bend space-time to create travel that would seem faster than light.

And in the Nation X story line, Magneto entered into a deep meditative catatonic state to focus his powers at an interstellar distance, reverse the path of Breakworld's "Earth-destroyer" Metal Bullet that Kitty Pryde was trapped in, and bring her home to Earth.